# Status code 500 when deleting an object using axios and symfony

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, symfony

I am working with "Symfony" framework with "vue.js", I installed existing project in localhost , Project is running but data is not showing, i checked in files and network(console) , actually Api(created in symfony) is not working, giving me "500 error" (maybe cors issue but not sure) , so how can i fix this issue ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try adding and setting up the debug component for Symfony:
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/components/debug.html
It might give you more details error message and the stack trace.
Then you can post your error here (with stack trace), and it might give us a clue as to help you

Comment: In general the status code 500 (Internal Server Error) is an error not treated in the server, not in the client

Comment: @AlexandreHeinen How can i solve this ?

Comment: You need to see the logs or debug your server application to see the error, and with this you can find the solution

Comment: @Rick did you found the problem?